# In R lubridate package, hour function returns wrong hour

Tags: r, lubridate, hour

I have a POSIXct time object of which I want to extract the hour. However the wrong hour is returned. My output is as follows.

```
> t
[1] "2018-04-09 09:05:25 CEST"
> class(t)
[1] "POSIXct"
> hour(t)
[1] 7
```

Anyone who knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Jordi

Comment: Not reproducible for me... `lubridate::hour(as.POSIXct("2018-04-09 09:05:25 CEST"))` returns 9.

Comment: possible there are two different system times/timezones defined? One in R and one on the operating system, and R is converting somewhere?

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Maybe add how you made the POSIXct time object?

Comment: Is it possible another package is loaded besides `lubridate` with an `hour` function?

Answer (score 0):

I find `lubridate`'s `ymd()` and `ymd_hms()` (and other combinations like `ydm()`) very handy:

```
library(lubridate)
t <- ymd_hms("2018-04-09 09:05:25 CEST")
hour(t) 
# [1] 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help.

I found a solution, brought to the idea by [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33517619/6086115).

Like you, I could not reproduce the answer in an isolated environment iether. However, since my "t" value was coming from a DataFrame, implicit type casting seems to have caused the value to be stored differently than in the isolated environment.

For comparison, in my isolated environment I would get the following,

```
> t = as.POSIXct("2018-04-09 09:05:25")
> t
[1] "2018-04-09 09:05:25 CEST"
> as.character(t)
[1] "2018-04-09 09:05:25"
```

whereas in my own code with the t coming from the DataFrame I would get

```
> t = tb[i, "time"]
> t
[1] "2018-04-09 09:05:25 CEST"
> as.character(t)
[1] "1523257525"
```

In other words, internally something is different - which, by the way, I still can't get a grip on.

It can however be "fixed" by casting in the following way:

```
t = as.POSIXct(as.numeric(t), origin="1970-01-01")
```